# Vue Axios Interceptor Response Firebase 401 Token Expired/Refresh (undefined)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios, vuex, interceptor

I'm using the following interceptors in a Vuejs v2 website to push a firebase token to my node backend. There in the backend, I detect/verify the token, pull some data using the uid from a database and then process any api calls.

Even though I am using the firebase **onIdTokenChanged** to automatically retrieve new ID tokens, sometimes, if the user is logged in, yet inactive for an hour, the token expires without refreshing. Now, this isn't a huge deal - I could check in the axios response interceptor and push them to a login page, but that seems annoying, if I can detect a 401 token expired, resend the axios call and have a refreshed token, the user won't even know it happened if they happen to interact with a component that requires data from an API call. So here is what I have:

**main.js**

```js
Vue.prototype.$axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
     const token = store.getters.getSessionToken;
     config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
     return config; 
});

 

Vue.prototype.$axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response   }, async function (error) {
    let originalRequest = error.config
  
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      let user = auth.currentUser;
      await store.dispatch("setUser", {user: user, refresh: true}).then(() => {
        const token = store.getters.getSessionToken;
        Vue.prototype.$axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        return Vue.prototype.$axios.request(originalRequest);
      });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);   });


let app;

auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
  await store.dispatch("setUser", {user: user, refresh: false}).then(() => {
    if (!app) {
      app = new Vue({
        router,
        store,
        vuetify,
        render: h => h(App)
      }).$mount('#app')
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }); 
});
```

**vuex**

```js
setUser({dispatch, commit}, {user, refresh}) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if(user)
      {   
        user.getIdToken(refresh).then(token => {
          commit('SET_SESSION_TOKEN', token);
          this._vm.$axios.get('/api/user/session').then((response) => {
              if(response.status === 200) {
                commit('SET_SESSION_USER', response.data);
                resolve(response);
              }
           })
          .catch(error => {
              dispatch('logout');
              dispatch('setSnackbar', {
                color: "error",
                timeout: 4000,
                text: 'Server unavailable: '+error
              });
              resolve();
          });
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch('logout');
          dispatch('setSnackbar', {
            color: "error",
            timeout: 4000,
            text: 'Unable to verify auth token.'+error
          });
          resolve();
      });
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('running logout');
          commit('SET_SESSION_USER', null);
          commit('SET_SESSION_TOKEN', null);
        resolve();
      }  
    })
  },
```

I am setting the token in vuex and then using it in the interceptors for all API calls. So the issue I am seeing with this code is, I'm making an API call with an expired token to the backend. This returns a 401 and the axios response interceptor picks it up and goes through the process of refreshing the firebase token. This then makes a new API call with the same config as the original to the backend with the updated token and returns it to the original API call (below).

This all *seems* to work, and I can see in dev tools/network, the response from the API call is sending back the correct data. However, it seems to be falling into the catch of the following api call/code. I get an **"undefined"** when trying to load the form field with response.data.server, for example. This page loads everything normally if I refresh the page (again, as it should with the normal token/loading process), so I know there aren't loading issues.

**vue component (loads smtp settings into the page)**

```js
getSMTPSettings: async function() {
    await this.$axios.get('/api/smtp')
      .then((response) => {
        this.form.server = response.data.server;
        this.form.port = response.data.port;
        this.form.authemail = response.data.authemail;
        this.form.authpassword = response.data.authpassword;
        this.form.sendemail = response.data.sendemail;
        this.form.testemail = response.data.testemail;
        this.form.protocol = response.data.protocol;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  },
```

I have been looking at this for a few days and I can't figure out why it won't load it. The data seems to be there. Is the timing of what I'm doing causing me issues? It doesn't appear to be a CORS problem, I am not getting any errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is mixing async / await with `.then()`. Your response interceptor isn't returning the next response because you've wrapped that part in `then()` without returning the outer promise.

Keep things simple with async / await everywhere.

Also, setting common headers defeats the point in using interceptors. You've already got a request interceptor, let it do its job

```js
// wait for this to complete
await store.dispatch("setUser", { user, refresh: true })

// your token is now in the store and can be used by the request interceptor
// re-run the original request
return Vue.prototype.$axios.request(originalRequest)
```

---

Your store action also falls into the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/283366) and can be simplified

```js
async setUser({ dispatch, commit }, { user, refresh }) {
  if(user) {
    try {
      const token = await user.getIdToken(refresh);
      commit('SET_SESSION_TOKEN', token);
      try {
        const { data } = await this._vm.$axios.get('/api/user/session');
        commit('SET_SESSION_USER', data);
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch('logout');
        dispatch('setSnackbar', {
          color: "error",
          timeout: 4000,
          text: `Server unavailable: ${err.response?.data ?? err.message}`
        })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch('logout');
      dispatch('setSnackbar', {
        color: "error",
        timeout: 4000,
        text: `Unable to verify auth token. ${error}`
      })
    }
  } else {
    console.log('running logout');
    commit('SET_SESSION_USER', null);
    commit('SET_SESSION_TOKEN', null);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Completely overlooked that. It makes sense and your solution works perfectly, thank you!